# Sort array of days from a specific start date

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, days

I have this array of days in a random order :

```
$jour_planning[] = "friday";
$jour_planning[] = "wednesday";
$jour_planning[] = "monday";
$jour_planning[] = "tuesday";
$jour_planning[] = "thursday";
$jour_planning[] = "sunday";
$jour_planning[] = "saturday";
```

If we are today a "tuesday", I would like to have this new array :

```
$jour_planning[] = "wednesday";
$jour_planning[] = "thursday";
$jour_planning[] = "friday";
$jour_planning[] = "saturday";
$jour_planning[] = "sunday";
$jour_planning[] = "monday";
$jour_planning[] = "tuesday";
```

How can do that, with usort() ?

Regards,
Vianney

Comment: You can do it using `array_shift` and `array_push`.

Comment: Yeah ^ or find today then splice the array after and before and merge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rearrange your array using [`uksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php), [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

```
function sort_week_days( $t1, $t2 ) {
        $weekdays = array( 'sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday' );
        foreach ( $weekdays as $key => $value ) {
            $weekdays[ $key ] = date( 'w', strtotime( $value ) );
        }

        $t1_time = date( 'w', strtotime( strtolower( $t1 ) ) );
        $t2_time = date( 'w', strtotime( strtolower( $t2 ) ) );

        return array_search( $t1_time, $weekdays ) - array_search( $t2_time, $weekdays );
    }
```

You need to pass your random array as below :

```
usort($jour_planning, "sort_week_days");
```

Then you can used your array in below code :

```
$day = date('w'); // You need to change to date('w', '-1day'); get result from today.

for ($i=0; $i <= $day ; $i++) {
   array_push($jour_planning, array_shift($jour_planning));
}
```

Comment: Great, it's working. And what about if I want the array to start the same day as today ?

Comment: @via You need to add `$day = date('w', '-1day');`.

Comment: Hum, I tried few array and this one is not working, do you know why ?

   $jour_planning[] = "wednesday";
   $jour_planning[] = "thursday";
   $jour_planning[] = "friday";
   $jour_planning[] = "saturday";
   $jour_planning[] = "sunday";

Comment: @Via Because of `Monday` and `Tuesday` missing form your array.

Comment: @Via As per your question, I have answer what you need. If you have any other issue than you need to ask on separate question.

Comment: Can you check this new question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52609888/sorting-array-of-days-from-a-random-order-with-a-specific-start-date

Answer (score 2):

I would first sort the array (and avoid french and english naming :) ).

Then, loop that sorted array and store into 2 separates array the days before the expected one (including this one), and the days after.

And finally, merge both arrays.

There's certainly better ways to do that.

```
$jour_planning[] = "friday";
$jour_planning[] = "wednesday";
$jour_planning[] = "monday";
$jour_planning[] = "tuesday";
$jour_planning[] = "thursday";
$jour_planning[] = "sunday";
$jour_planning[] = "saturday";

$sorted_days_planning = array(1 => null, 2 => null, 3 => null, 4 => null, 5 => null, 6 => null, 7 => null);

foreach ($jour_planning as $value)
{
    $day_of_week = date('N', strtotime($value));
    $sorted_days_planning[$day_of_week] = $value;
}

$final_days_planning = array();

$day_to_start = "tuesday";
$day_found = false;
$temp_array = array();
foreach ($sorted_days_planning as $value)
{
    if (!$day_found)
    {
        $temp_array[] = $value;
        if ($day_to_start == $value)
            $day_found = true;
    }
    else
        $final_days_planning[] = $value;
}

$final_days_planning = array_merge($final_days_planning, $temp_array);

var_dump($final_days_planning);
```

Outputs :

```
array(6) {
    [0]=> string(9) "wednesday"
    [1]=> string(8) "thursday"
    [2]=> string(6) "friday"
    [3]=> string(8) "saturday"
    [4]=> string(6) "sunday"
    [5]=> string(6) "monday"
    [6]=> string(7) "tuesday"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of your array is randomly ordered, there is no other way to order it correctly, then doing it by hand (you cannot order the array numerically or alphabetically - it can be done by calculating the days by the `datetime()` function, see [@Cid's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607966/9421134) answer), so:

```
/*
$jour_planning = [];

$jour_planning[] = "friday";
$jour_planning[] = "wednesday";
$jour_planning[] = "monday";
$jour_planning[] = "tuesday";
$jour_planning[] = "thursday";
$jour_planning[] = "sunday";
$jour_planning[] = "saturday";
*/

$days = [
    0 => 'monday',
    1 => 'tuesday',
    2 => 'wednesday',
    3 => 'thursday',
    4 => 'friday',
    5 => 'saturday',
    6 => 'sunday'
];

$today = array_search(strtolower(date('l')), $days);
$tomorrow = ($today === 6) ? 0 : $today + 1;
$reordered = array_merge(array_slice($days, $tomorrow), array_slice($days, 0, $tomorrow));

print_r($reordered);
```

Firstly you have to search the current day, then add 1 to the index of this day and you have the day, that will be tomorrow. Now, when you have this index, you simply create 2 arrays: the first one starting from the day of tomorrow and the second one starting from index 0 to the day of today. Then merge this two arrays together and you have exactly what you wanted to have.

Comment: You can order it. Check my answer.

Comment: @Cid Yes, you can order it by calculating the date day by day, of course then there will be more performance-cost.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to sort week days and it's has option to include the first day.

```
function sort_days($day_to_start = 'monday', $include_first_day = true)
{
    $final_days_planning = [];
    $rest_days = [];
    $first_day_found = 0;
    foreach ([ "sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday" ] as $day)
    {
        if (!$first_day_found){
            if ($day_to_start == $day){
                $first_day_found = 1;
                if($include_first_day){
                    $final_days_planning[] = $day;
                }
                else
                {
                    $rest_days[] = $day;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $rest_days[] = $day;
            }
        } else{
            $final_days_planning[] = $day;
        }
    }
    return array_merge($final_days_planning, $rest_days);
}
```

To try it:

```
$days = sort_days('wednesday');
print_r($days);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use in_array to find the days present in your array and add to new array.

```
$jour_planning=["saturday","wednesday","friday","thursday"];

public function getSortedDays($jour_planning){     
    $sorted_days=[];   
    for($i=1;$i<=7;$i++){
        $day = date("l", strtotime("+$i days"));
        $_day = strtolower($day);
        if(in_array($_day, $jour_planning)){
            $sorted_days[] = $_day;
        }
    }
    return $sorted_days;
}

$sorted_days = getSortedDays($jour_planning);

print_r($sorted_days); //Array ( [0] => wednesday [1] => thursday [2] => friday [3] => saturday )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    while (end($jour_planning) !== "tuesday") {
        array_unshift($jour_planning, array_pop($jour_planning));
    }
```

Comment: This solution will just shift the current array, it will not reorder it.