# Sorting array of days from a random order with a specific start date

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have this kind of array of days in a random order (number of days can be 1 until 5) :

```
$jour_planning[] = "sunday";
$jour_planning[] = "wednesday";
$jour_planning[] = "monday";
```

I would like to sort them, starting of "today".

I have this code working but only for 7 days in the array, how to adapt it ?

```
function sort_week_days( $t1, $t2 ) {
        $weekdays = array( 'sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday' );
        foreach ( $weekdays as $key => $value ) {
            $weekdays[ $key ] = date( 'w', strtotime( $value ) );
        }

        $t1_time = date( 'w', strtotime( strtolower( $t1 ) ) );
        $t2_time = date( 'w', strtotime( strtolower( $t2 ) ) );

        return array_search( $t1_time, $weekdays ) - array_search( $t2_time, $weekdays );
}

usort($jour_planning, "sort_week_days");
$today_day = date('w', '-1day');
for ($i=0; $i <= $today_day ; $i++) {
   array_push($jour_planning, array_shift($jour_planning));
}
```

Comment: how about array_diff?

Comment: Use the same function - it will work

Comment: the result is : Array ( [0] => sunday [1] => monday [2] => wednesday ) but it should be Array ( [0] => wednesday [1] => sunday [2] => monday ) 
=> as we are Tuesday today